# Azure B2C Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory

I would like to use Azure B2C Active Directory and source users under local account as email (`joe@some-email.com`) and also as username (for example - `joe123`).
Within the portal, under local accounts in B2C, you can select either `email` or `username` and I cannot find a way to add both types of local accounts, appears it’s mutually exclusive between email type or username type.

Wanted to confirm, if there a way to configure `B2C` that works with both types of sign-ins where a user can provide any valid email no matter what the domain is and at the same time allow users to sign-in by just providing a username.
In case they are exclusive, is there a preferred solution that would allow both type of sign-in to coexist.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use both of them, as if local account set to use email then that email goes to username field inside user account. There is also email claim in user account profile. But if let's say you select local account with email and also select that claim again email will be asked once and only go to username field. Also email uniqueness will be checked only if it is used for sign-in. If you use username for local account sign-in then multiple users can be registered with same valid email